# SVM - How to use 3D point as an input in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, svm, libsvm

I've got vector which consists of 3D points and I want to use it as an input for SVM (LibSVM or OpenCV). Is it possible? Or how to convert 3D point to 2D without loosing 3rd dimension information.

If you will have some other solution of this problem I'll realy appreciate it!!

Thank you in advance

Comment: ... and why do you want to convert to 2D?

Comment: Because I realized that OpenCV SVM allows me to use two dimensinal input only

Comment: you realized it wrong ;) Input must be a 2D matrix, but that doesn't mean that your data must be 2 dimensional. In this case you can have a Nx3 matrix (which is 2D), with one 3D point per line...

Comment: I have a lot of sets of 3D points. Example of one set: {(1.32 , 4.43 , 0.22);(2.43 , 1.67 , 0.87 );(1.35 , 8.43 , 0,01)}. Each of these sets represents one object (one object is described by 4 3D points)
Soo.. If I have 4 3D points in each set, there will be Nx12 matrix, right?

Comment: `Nx12`. Each of your objects is represented by a 12 dimensional feature: `x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3`. You put each feature in a row, so if you have `N` features (your objects) you end up with a `Nx12` matrix